# PrivateRoute not redirecting to specified route when there are no user logged in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I am using firebase to handle the register login and logout. I made my "/" to a private route so that when the currentUser logged in, it will allow the user to visit that route but if there are no currentUser logged in, it will redirect to "/login route.

However it still tries to render the "/" even if there are no logged in users or after the user click log out resulting to errors

Here is the error

[image]

Here is my PrivateRoute.js

[image]

Here is the logout button handler

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar using the following example hopefully it solves your issue, I think how you have done it is slightly complex I prefer to use history.push to redirect.

I find the below easier to read and works in my projects.

```
  const history = useHistory();
  const currentUser = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!currentUser) {
      history.push('/login')
    }
  }, [currentUser]);

  return (
    <Route
      {...props}
      component={props.component} />
  );
```